# Dynamically get the source strings of clojure multimethod implementation

Tags: clojure

I am interested in getting the source strings of all the implementations of clojure multimethods for documentation purposes.

Something similar to

```
(->> (methods my-multimethod)
     (map (fn [[k f]] (clojure.repl/source-fn f))))
```

clojure.repl/source-fn does not work because it requires the source code to be on disk or something to that effect.

Any idea how I can get to the source dynamically similar to above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defmethod` does not produce a var, which could have been used by `clojure.repl/source-fn`.

The only way I can see is to get through all the source files and filter all the `defmethod` definitions.